# Why Tensorflow reports smaller GPU's memory_limit than it actually has?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 02 environments for Python (under Anaconda) as follows:

(1) 'py37' - CUDA Toolkit v10.1, cuDNN v7.6, Python v3.7 and Tensorflow 2.3.0
(2) 'py39' - CUDA Toolkit v11.2, cuDNN v8.1.1, Python v3.9 and Tensorflow 2.9.0

My GPU is ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1650 with 4Gb.

I need to use the environment 'py39' for compatibility w/ other applications but I'm facing the following issues:

**The Problems**

(1) Apparently Tensorflow is recognizing more memory of my GPU in environment 'py37' (3Gb) and in 'py39' (2Gb) and I don't know why (I have also tried 'py39' with CUDA v11.7 and cuDNN v8.4 w/ same results).

(see `memory_limit` below on each environment)

a. **Environment 'py39'**

```
(base) PS C:\Users\lacor> conda activate py39
(py39) PS C:\Users\lacor> python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:146: UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.23.1
  warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion}"
>>> my_devs = device_lib.list_local_devices()
2022-08-05 16:44:01.720845: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-08-05 16:44:04.501487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 2147 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
>>> my_devs
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 16088886217052679741
xla_global_id: -1
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 2252026676
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 8733510302035549726
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
xla_global_id: 416903419
]
>>> exit()
(py39) PS C:\Users\lacor> conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py39:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

b. **Environment 'py37'**

```
(py39) PS C:\Users\lacor> conda activate py37
(py37) PS C:\Users\lacor> python
Python 3.7.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 08:03:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.WCDJNK7YVMPZQ2ME2ZZHJJRJ3JIKNDB7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
2022-08-05 16:45:42.365589: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
>>> my_devs = device_lib.list_local_devices()
2022-08-05 16:46:14.160053: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-08-05 16:46:14.191914: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x23fd749dc90 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-08-05 16:46:14.192048: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2022-08-05 16:46:14.195509: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.224159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.62GHz coreCount: 14 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2022-08-05 16:46:14.224365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.258949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.294059: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.302072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.340330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.358147: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.435076: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2022-08-05 16:46:14.435330: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-08-05 16:46:15.433038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-08-05 16:46:15.433244: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0
2022-08-05 16:46:15.434207: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N
2022-08-05 16:46:15.435567: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 2903 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2022-08-05 16:46:15.439714: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2400ce94710 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-08-05 16:46:15.439794: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, Compute Capability 7.5
>>> my_devs
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4100643938597851748
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 6978060269302711410
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3044750132
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 6665762401071882742
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3607455137205668610
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
>>> exit()
(py37) PS C:\Users\lacor> conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at C:\Users\lacor\anaconda3\envs\py37:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py37h10aaca4_0
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py37h17acbac_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.6.0              pyh7b7c402_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu-estimator  2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

(2) I also noted a difference in performance of both environments where the same command for training a LSTM Neural Network takes 3.11s/epoch in 'py37' (faster) and 4.14s/epoch in py39.

```
    with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
        Model = Sequential()
        Model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(n_nodes,return_sequences=False),input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
        Model.add(Dense(n_nodes*8))
        Model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        Model.add(Dense(n_nodes*4))
        Model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        Model.add(Dense(n_nodes*2))
        Model.add(Dropout(dropout))
        Model.add(Dense(n_out,activation='tanh'))
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learn_rate)  # (lr=learn_rate)
        Model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=optimizer)
```

Does anyone had a similar problem and/or know how to solve it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running anything else? Tensorflow *tries* to allocate 100% available memory. That doesn't necessarily mean it successfully gets the full available amount, and that doesn't mean it's the total amount either.

Comment: No, in fact I was running only this notebook in Google Collab under a local runtime. The differences are on these two Tensorflows on each environment. I noticed that py37`s uses a lot of specific DLLs, not sure if it is due to be a recompiled version. What doesn't make sense to me is an older version performing better than a new one.

Comment: It seems #py37 environment has an optimized version of Tensorflow (`This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2`). What should I do to optimize Tensorflow for #py39 env?